# KeyboardAvoidingView is not working in my code -react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, tpkeyboardavoiding

In my code I am capturing some details of as user . there are many input fields and drop downs .
No everything is working fine all values is populting ,able to chnage the value and get all data .
But I am implementing "KeyboardAvoidingView"  to avoind keyboard which is overlaping my screen .
Like when I am clicking belwo input filed keyboard is coming but its overlaping the field .While it should move up automatic . I saw some thing about "KeyboardAvoidingView" I tyried alos but Its not working . Please sugget where I am going wrong . I have pasted my whold UI code here .

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Item, Input } from 'native-base';
    import { View, Dimensions, ScrollView,KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';
    import _ from 'lodash';
    import { RegularText, SmallText } from '../ui/text';
    import { widthPercentageToDP as wp, heightPercentageToDP as hp } from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
    import { CustomButton } from '../ui/buttons';
    import parentStyle from '../../themes/parent.style';
    import DatePicker from '../ui/datePicker';
    import { getToday, formatDate, addSubtractDate, getDate } from '../../dateFormat';
    import SelectField from '../ui/selectField';
    import StagedHeader from '../ui/stagedHeader';
    import Modal from "react-native-modal";
    import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';

    const minDate = '01/01/1970';
    const format = 'DD/MM/YYYY';
    const currentDate = formatDate(addSubtractDate(getToday(), 'substract', 'year', 18));
    const deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
    const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

    class PersonalDetails extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            let category = [];
            let subCategory = [];
            let nationality = [];
            let defaultNationality = 0;
            let defaultCategory = 0;
            let defaultSubCategory = 0;
            props.categoryArray.map((cat, index) => {
                const value = cat.code;
                const label = cat.name;
                category.push({ value, label });
                if (cat.default === 'true') {
                    defaultCategory = index;
                    cat.subCategory.map((sub, index) => {
                        const value = sub.code;
                        const label = sub.name;
                        if (sub.default === 'true') {
                            defaultSubCategory = index;
                        }
                        subCategory.push({ value, label });
                    })
                }
            })
            props.nationalityArray.map((nat, index) => {
                const value = nat.code;
                const label = nat.name;
                nationality.push({ value, label });
            });
            this.state = {
                dateOfBirth: currentDate,
                firstName: props.firstName || '',
                lastName: props.lastName || '',
                customerCategoryOptions: category,
                customerSubCategoryOptions: subCategory,
                customerCategory: category[defaultCategory].value,
                customerSubCategory: subCategory[defaultSubCategory].value,
                uniqueIdNo: '',
                nationalityOptions: nationality,
                nationality: nationality[defaultNationality].value,
                riskCategory: props.riskCategory
            }
            this.fetchRiskCategory(category[defaultCategory].value, subCategory[defaultSubCategory].value);
        }
        fetchRiskCategory = async (customerCategory, customerSubCategory) => {
            await this.props.fetchRiskCategory(customerCategory, customerSubCategory);
            this.setState({
                riskCategory: this.props.riskCategory
            })
        }

        nextStep = async () => {
            const { firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth, customerCategory, customerSubCategory, uniqueIdNo, nationality, riskCategory } = this.state;
            const dob = dateOfBirth.split('/');
            const personalDetails = {
                firstName: firstName,
                lastName: lastName,
                dateOfBirth: getDate(`${dob[2]}-${dob[1]}-${dob[0]}`),
                customerCategory: customerCategory,
                customerSubCategory: customerSubCategory,
                uniqueIdNo: uniqueIdNo,
                nationality: nationality,
                riskCategory: riskCategory
            };
            this.props.nextStep(personalDetails, this);
        };

        onChangeText = async (text, identifier) => {
            if (identifier === 'FN') {
                this.setState({
                    firstName: text
                })
            } else if (identifier === 'LN') {
                this.setState({
                    lastName: text
                })
            } else if (identifier === 'UIN') {
                this.setState({
                    uniqueIdNo: text
                })
            }
        }
        onPickerChange = async (key, value, identifier) => {
            let { categoryArray } = this.props;
            let defaultSubCategory = 0;
            let subCategory = [];
            if (identifier === 'CAT') {
                categoryArray.map((cat, index) => {
                    if (cat.code === value) {
                        cat.subCategory.map((sub, index) => {
                            const value = sub.code;
                            const label = sub.name;
                            if (sub.default === 'true') {
                                defaultSubCategory = index;
                            }
                            subCategory.push({ value, label });
                        })
                    }
                })
                this.setState({
                    customerSubCategoryOptions: subCategory,
                    customerSubCategory: subCategory[defaultSubCategory].value,
                    customerCategory: value
                });
                await this.fetchRiskCategory(value, subCategory[defaultSubCategory].value);
            } else if (identifier === 'SCAT') {
                this.setState({
                    customerSubCategory: value
                });
                await this.fetchRiskCategory(this.state.customerCategory, value);
            } else if (identifier === 'NAT') {
                this.setState({
                    nationality: value
                });
            }
        }
        onDateChange = async (value) => {
            this.setState({
                dateOfBirth: value
            });
        }

        render() {
            const { navigation, appliedTheme, appliedMode, isLoading } = this.props;
            const { firstName, lastName, customerCategory, customerSubCategory, nationality, uniqueIdNo,
                nationalityOptions, customerCategoryOptions, customerSubCategoryOptions, riskCategory } = this.state;
            let signatureHeadingColor = parentStyle[appliedTheme] ? parentStyle[appliedTheme][appliedMode].signatureHeadingColor : null
            if (navigation.length === 0) {
                return (
                    <View>
                        <NoDataFound imageType='record' />
                    </View>
                );
            }
            return (
                <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', height: '100%' }}>
                    <Modal isVisible={isLoading} coverScreen={true}>
                        <View style={{ height: deviceHeight, width: deviceWidth }}>
                            <LottieView source={require('../animations/login_authentication.json')} autoPlay loop />
                        </View>
                    </Modal>
                    <StagedHeader navigation={navigation} subtitle={'Personal Details'}
                        backgroundColor={'#F3F4F9'} subTitleColor={'#67809F'} backButtonColor={'#67809F'}
                        totalSteps={2} currentStep={1} stepsColor={signatureHeadingColor} />
                        <KeyboardAvoidingView>
                    <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                        <View style={{ paddingLeft: 15, paddingTop: 10 }}>
                            <RegularText text={'PERSONAL INFO'} textColor='#989898' fontWeight='bold' style={{ fontSize: hp('2%') }} />
                        </View>
                        <View style={{ padding: 15 }}>

                            <View style={{ marginTop: 15 }}>
                                <View style={{
                                    flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#fff'
                                }}>
                                    <SmallText textColor="#4A494A" text={`First Name`} />
                                </View>
                                <Item style={{ borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth: 0.6 }}>
                                    <Input
                                        value={firstName}
                                        keyboardType='default'
                                        onChangeText={(text) => this.onChangeText(text, 'FN')}
                                    />
                                </Item>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ marginTop: 15 }}>
                                <View style={{
                                    flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#fff'
                                }}>
                                    <SmallText textColor="#4A494A" text={`Last Name`} />
                                </View>
                                <Item style={{ borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth: 0.6 }}>
                                    <Input
                                        value={lastName}
                                        keyboardType='default'
                                        onChangeText={(text) => this.onChangeText(text, 'LN')}
                                    />
                                </Item>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ marginTop: 15 }}>

                                <SelectField
                                    label="Customer Category"
                                    options={customerCategoryOptions}
                                    value={customerCategory}
                                    onChange={(key, value) => this.onPickerChange(key, value, 'CAT')}
                                    that={this}
                                    setIcon={true}
                                    textColor='#4A494A'
                                />
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '.1%', backgroundColor: 'black' }}></View>
                            <View style={{ marginTop: 15 }}>

                                <SelectField
                                    label="Sub Category"
                                    options={customerSubCategoryOptions}
                                    value={customerSubCategory}
                                    onChange={(key, value) => this.onPickerChange(key, value, 'SCAT')}
                                    that={this}
                                    setIcon={true}
                                    textColor='#4A494A'
                                />
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '.1%', backgroundColor: 'black' }}></View>
                            {riskCategory !== '' && <View style={{ marginTop: 15 }}>
                                <View style={{
                                    flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#fff'
                                }}>
                                    <SmallText textColor="#4A494A" text={`Risk Category`} />
                                </View>
                                <Item style={{ borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth: 0.6 }}>
                                    <Input editable={false}
                                        value={riskCategory}
                                        keyboardType='default'
                                    />
                                </Item>
                            </View>}
                            <View style={{ marginTop: 15 }}>
                                <View style={{
                                    flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#fff'
                                }}>
                                    <SmallText textColor="#4A494A" text={`Unique Identification Number`} />
                                </View>
                                <Item style={{ borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth: 0.6 }}>
                                    <Input
                                        value={uniqueIdNo}
                                        onChangeText={(text) => this.onChangeText(text, 'UIN')}
                                    />
                                </Item>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ marginTop: 15 }}>

                                <SelectField
                                    label="Nationality"
                                    options={nationalityOptions}
                                    value={nationality}
                                    node="Gender"
                                    onChange={(key, value) => this.onPickerChange(key, value, 'NAT')}
                                    that={this}
                                    setIcon={true}
                                    textColor='#4A494A'
                                />
                            </View>
                            <View style={{ width: '100%', height: '.1%', backgroundColor: 'black' }}></View>
                            <View style={{ marginTop: 15,marginBottom:40 }}>
                                <View style={{
                                    flexDirection: 'row', backgroundColor: '#fff'
                                }}>
                                    <SmallText textColor="#4A494A" text={`Date of Birth`} />
                                </View>
                                <Item style={{ borderColor: '#00fff', borderBottomWidth: 0.6 }}>
                                    <DatePicker
                                        minDate={minDate}
                                        maxDate={currentDate}
                                        currentDate={this.state.dateOfBirth}
                                        format={format}
                                        width={deviceWidth}
                                        onChange={(dateOfBirth) => this.onDateChange(dateOfBirth)}
                                        marginLeft={0}
                                    />
                                </Item>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </ScrollView>
                    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
                    <View style={{ alignSelf: 'center', paddingTop: 20, position: 'absolute', bottom: 10 }}>
                        <CustomButton backgroundColor={parentStyle[appliedTheme] ? parentStyle[appliedTheme][appliedMode].primaryButtonColor : null}
                            width={deviceWidth - 30} label={'Proceed'} height={60} 
                            disabled={!this.state.firstName || !this.state.lastName || !this.state.uniqueIdNo }
                            onPress={() => this.nextStep()} labelFontSize={hp('2.5%')}>
                        </CustomButton>
                    </View>

                </View>

            );
        }
    }
    export default PersonalDetails;
```

Thanks 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Solved ..

```
const keyboardVerticalOffset = Platform.OS === 'ios' ?hp('8%') : hp('8%');

 retuen(
 <KeyboardAvoidingView  behavior={'position'} keyboardVerticalOffset={keyboardVerticalOffset} >
///// 
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced  Keyboard Avoiding View with

```
     <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={Platform.OS == 'ios' ? 'padding' : null} >
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

then I see.That solved my problem :)

Comment: Thanks... could you please have a look on my code , where should I write this

Comment: I seen your code you can replace keyboardAvoidingview with my code. Nice to meet you

Comment: can you share with  me screenshot?

Comment: attache dthe screenshot